# Unable to startproject with Scrapy dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, scrapy

I'm new to installing packages in unix and python. I'm working on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.
I wanted to start learning Scrapy, which I installed using:

```
apt-get install scrapy
```

When I'm trying to create a project, I'm getting the following error:

```
root > scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 128, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

I verified that the above file is available. I'm trying to understand if there is any prerequisite(s) I missed to install (which I doubt, as I understand that they are handled during installation - please correct me if I'm wrong), or is there anything I need to enable.

Thanks, Sasi

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `apt-get` to install scrapy as it will have very old version. You should do it like below

```
apt install -y python python-pip
```

And then use below to install scrapy

```
pip install --force --upgrade scrapy
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun. But 2 questions: How should I uninstall the current install And so which of the above 2 commands should I use - should I use both (can you please explain the difference between the above two)?

Comment: You need to use both. First one ensures that you have python and pip installed. Which you may already have. Second one is to install scrapy

Comment: Ok. So how would you suggest me to uninstall my existing scrapy package. Also, I had tried to create a virtual environment wherein I installed scrapy with the pip option - I was getting the same error as above.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my late response - had to be away for a while. I am using the Windows 10, and the bash which came along with it.

Comment: For Windows OS try using `easy_install scrapy`

Comment: Sorry if my answer was misleading, I meant I'm using the BashOnUbuntuOnWindows. I should have replied as Bash for your question.